# .htaccess redirect, from old dirty URL to a clean new URL with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following 2 links, I'm not great with .htaccess rules *yet*.

```
Old URL: http://www.mywebsite.org.uk/donate/donate.php?charity_id=885&project_id=18111
New URL: http://new.mywebsite.org.uk/donation/to/885/18111
```

I want all the traffic coming from the old URL to the new url (including the parameters `charity_id` & `project_id`).

I'm trying to learn .htaccess rules, but finding the tutorials online to be kinda vague.

I'd really like a simple explanation on the .htaccess rules.

(Give a man a fish, feed him for a day, ***teach a man to fish, feed him for a lifetime***).

The correct answer will be the answer with a simple and useful explanation (along with the rules if possible!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To learn to set up .htaccess rules you at least need some little regexp skills and be confident to use mod_rewrite Apache module, since it comes handy to build rewriting rules thanks to its flexibility.

If so, your code can be like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^charity_id=([0-9]+)&project_id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule donate/donate.php http://new.mywebsite.org.uk/donation/to/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

At http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html (for 2.4 Apache version, choose a different one if applicable) is available an useful reference, so you have to start from it, even for better understand the code above.

You can think at `RewriteRule` as the brick for rewriting, so every rule will use it at least once. You will going to add before `RewriteCond` when you need to check environment vars or to reference query string values, like in our piece of code.

To place a backreference into substitution string coming from previous `RewriteCond` you will use from `%1` to `%9`
values; if you need backreference from first part of `RewriteRule` itself, you will use `$1` to `$9`.

Mind the question mark sign at the end of substitution url, since it's the way to skip off the query string; if missing, you will have the `?charity_id=885&project_id=18111` at the end of new url.

Answer (score 2):

In another post, sysadmin1138 has written a very good introduction into mod rewrite.

You can find the post [here](https://serverfault.com/a/214521/141615).

/EDIT:
Example:

```
old: http://example.com/path?var=val 
new: http://example.com/path/var/val
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^/path /path/%1/%2?
```